# need HTML or CSS code to display images in landscape orientation if on a mobile device

Tags: html, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I have certain rectangular images that I would like to display in landscape orientation if a mobile device is detected.

Images typically are 1600x800 pixels or some similar aspect ratio.  A square image (200x200) on the main page leads to the higher res images when clicked or tapped on.  These higher res images are what I want to display in landscape mode.

There is a backlink.  When this is clicked, it goes back to the page in portrait orientation.

I do not need to lock the landscape orientation but I do need the capability to display the image in landscape if the device is rotated that way.
Here is an illustration of the problem:
[image: Landscape Orientation failure]
I should also add that removing all the text and just posting the picture leads to the same problem: portrait orientation only.

The CSS coding for this page makes use of the MDN Web docs on orientation.  I implemented them but no change. These docs have an issue/problem which has now been reported to MDN.

My CSS for this page is as follows:

```
/* style for CoinPages  */
* {
/* margin: 1rem; */
padding: .25rem;
/*  outline: solid black 2px;  */
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
/* display: flex; */
}

@media (orientation: landscape)
{
body {
margin: .5rem;
padding: .5rem;
background-image:
url('..< truncated here ***.jpg');
background-size: auto;
img {
border:  1px;
background-color: transparent;
}
}
}

p {
color: black;
text-align: center;
font-family: Times, Times New Roman, serif;
font-size: 1.0rem;
padding: 1rem;
}

font {
font-family: Times serif;
text-align: center;
height: 1.1rem;
padding: 0rem;
margin: 0rem;
/* background-color: transparent; */

box-sizing: border-box;
outline: solid firebrick 2px;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.9;
}

.auth {
font-size: .9rem;
color: #404404;
}
```

An example of a page with the images I want to display is:
[main page](https://coinsandhistory.com/countries/Ancients_Rome/Ancients_46_Rome_Empire_Crisis.html) 
An example of the image I wish to display in landscape for mobile is:
[Image example, here 1100x600](https://coinsandhistory.com/countries/Ancients_Rome/Rome_Geta_tetradrachm.html)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation
This will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my CSS and see how it goes.   BTW (by the way) why was my question downgraded and I lost reputation?  The question is not a duplicate and I really need the answer.  I put time into trying to document my issue with illustrations. I'm sorry that it's not about some highly arcane topic in SQL or C++ programming.   If my reputation keeps dropping I won't be able to use SO.

Comment: Thanks so much Behrouz.  I've attached a pix of my mobile device with the pix not in landscape mode as well as my CSS.  I truncated the URL for the background image and deleted some stuff for headers in my CSS to improve brevity.  I did follow the MDM guide for landscape orientation but no help.

Comment: Also the MDN web docs article (ref above) for this issue have been identified as misnamed or not working.